# Set RubyGems version on a per folder basis

Tags: rubygems, rvm

I found [this documentation](https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems). But it is not clear to me how specify RubyGems version in a `.ruby-version` file.

Comment: What do you mean by version of rubygems? bundler's version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7 -n rg142
$ rvm rubygems 1.4.2
$ echo '1.8.7-p374-rg142' > .ruby-version
$ rvm rvmrc load
```